# Prevent recording vertical videos in app

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am creating an iOS app that allows users to take photos and record videos. I would like to block recording "vertical" videos - video recording in portrait orientations. I couldn't find any software libraries that implement this functionality so I guess I will have to implement it myself.

I am using UIImagePickerController and I tried to achieve that using cameraOverlayView, but I don't believe it can be done that way.

So is there any way to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually the videos are always recorded in landscape-right regardless of the device orientation b/c that's how the sensor is oriented in the hardware ([although you can request rotated buffers in AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AudioVideo/RN-AVFoundation/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010717-CH1-DontLinkElementID_12)). However there's a flag stored as video metadata that describes the device's orientation during recording and this is used during playback to rotate the content. See [AVAssetTrack preferredTransform](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetTrack_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetTrack/preferredTransform). 
If you don't want your video to be rotated, just discard this information during playback.